# On Appium, for iOS, how to skip prompt for "Save Password" / "Not Now"

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

[image]

I'm working on automated tests for an iOS app and, after login, iOS opens a prompt to ask to save the password. What is the best way to skip this prompt? Ideally, is there a capability to handle this?

I'm using Appium 2.2, appium-chromedriver 5.6.5, working with typescript.

Update 0: I'm using the simulator, not the real device.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by set capability to {"autoAcceptAlert", true} And add condition as try element 'save Password' shown then click on on cancel else skip

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).